# jclRegistry (jesi 2.10) windows 7 delphi7

Tags: delphi-7, jedi-code-library

I am trying to to read registry key on Windows 7 using app compiled by Delphi 7 using jclRegistry from Jedi 2.10.

I've double checked registry using regedit and specified entry exists.

Unfortunately:
RegReadStringDef(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\7.0', 'RootDir', '') - returns ''

Is it a chance to fix it without upgradind jedi , delphi etc.
If it is could someone give advice please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see that particular registry Key is in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** and not in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**

The **RegReadStringDef** should work in your JEDI version too.